# Changing winform style in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, styles, inheritance, krypton-toolkit

Okay, so some of you may be familiar with the Krypton Toolkit by Component Factory. If not, check it out [here](http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3).

Anyways, you can change the form style completely using this toolkit by opening the designer code for your form and changing this line:

```
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

To this:

```
Inherits ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm
```

That is Visual Basic though. I would like to achieve this using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form's code-behind file instead of this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

type this:

```
public partial class Form1 : ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm
```

Note, that this isn't a changing of form's style, this is changing of base class. To open code-behind, you should press F7 in designer by default.

Answer (score 1):

in C# you have 2 cs files for your form.

Say your form is called `Form1`, you'll have to go to the file `Form1.cs` and change this line:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

to

```
public partial class Form1 : ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm
```

that should do the work